# Getting pandas to cache strings when creating large string-typed column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv, bigdata

Let's say I have a hdf5 and csv that contain a single column/dataset of equivalent string data of length 50 million. I read it in via hdf5

```py
foo = pd.DataFrame()
dataset = h5py.File(file)[column][:] # dtype = S10, length = 10 million
foo['a'] = dataset # dtype is still S10, described in issue
foo['a'] = foo['a'].astype(object)
```

At this point, the memory explodes to something colossal. By contrast, when I do

```
foo = pd.read_csv(large_file)
```

The memory stays really low, as though it is interning/caching the strings in the `read_csv` codepath. [And sure enough a pandas blog post says as much](https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2019/02/05/python-string-memory-0.12/):

> For many years, the pandas.read_csv function has relied on a trick to limit the amount of string memory allocated. Because pandas uses arrays of PyObject* pointers to refer to objects in the Python heap, we can avoid creating multiple strings with the same value, instead reusing existing objects and incrementing their reference counts.

Does such an optimization exist for column creation that doesn't use read_csv? The best trick I can find is to do

```
df[column].astype('category').astype(object)
```

but I am afraid of the consequences of doing this for datasets with many unique values.